# Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-native-reanimated'

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

Was working with react native and its navigation. Got this error while starting to work with the drawer and its features in the app.

I read somewhere few dependencies with their latest version in native is not co-dependant to each other. Is that a reason for this error?

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-native-reanimated'
  1 | import * as React from 'react';
  2 | import { Platform, Pressable, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
> 3 | import Animated from 'react-native-reanimated';  4 | 
  5 | const {
  6 |   // @ts-expect-error: this is to support reanimated 1
./node_modules/@react-navigation/drawer/lib/module/views/modern/Drawer.js:15
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-native-reanimated'
  13 |   State as GestureState,
  14 | } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';        
  16 |   interpolate,
  17 |   runOnJS,
  18 |   useAnimatedGestureHandler,
./node_modules/@react-navigation/drawer/lib/module/views/modern/Overlay.js:3
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-native-reanimated'
  1 | import * as React from 'react';
  2 | import { Platform, Pressable, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
> 3 | import Animated, {
  4 |   useAnimatedProps,
  5 |   useAnimatedStyle,
  6 | } from 'react-native-reanimated';
```

This is the Package.json

```
{
  "name": "newsapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.2.0",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.3.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.8",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.4.0",
    "expo": "~44.0.0",
    "expo-app-loading": "~1.3.0",
    "expo-font": "~10.0.4",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.2.0",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.1.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.3.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.10.1",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: Did you follow all of the steps in the doc? https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/fundamentals/installation

Comment: I did, and it's working now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

set version to
"react-native": "^0.68.2",
"react-native-reanimated": "^2.8.0",

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).